# Fancybox gallery applied to all images on the domain

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox-3

Trying to apply version [3 of fancybox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) with this given code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried this solution:

```
$('a').each(function () {
if ($(this).has('img')) {
    $(this).fancybox();
}
```

});

And I also tried a number of other solution including stackoverlow. And it doesn't seem to work. I don't look forward to do all the links by hand. The original fancybox gallery creator does not provide an option for handling all image links.

Answer (score 1):

This code works if you want all images in your html file should be fancybox.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <img src="./img/img-small-1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="./img/img-small-2.jpg" alt="">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />      
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("img").wrap(function() {
      return "<a href=" + this.src + " data-fancybox></a>";
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But mostly fancybox will added to your image in html file like this (not in script file)

```html
  <a href="./img/img-small-1.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery"><img src="./img/img-small-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a href="./img/img-small-2.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery"><img src="./img/img-small-2.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: hhhm. Doesn't seem to work. Check the photocamera photo in the middle on this page - http://2vsk.liepaja.edu.lv/blueprint.php

It only works on the videocamera photo because I have put the data-fancybox parameter right into it.

Comment: you placed script in head, so script is running before html document will be loadded. so you must write like that if you script placed in head. `$(document).ready(function() { $("img").wrap(function() {
      return "<a href=" + this.src + " data-fancybox></a>";
    }); });`

Comment: Thanks. Got it working, when the script was placed in <body> tag. One thing though. Now it is applied to every img instance, whereas I require only img with <a> tag. Plus, the image has moved the text in the menu to another line. Example here - http://2vsk.liepaja.edu.lv/exp.php